# Play framework: Enabling database evolution for oracle

Tags: oracle, playframework, playframework-evolutions, playframework-2.3

There is a [bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2286) in play framework. According to this bug, `play_evolutions` can not instantiate for Oracle databases.
As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250483/play-framework-using-oracle-database-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist?answertab=votes) I am using following script for generating `play_evolutions` table manually:

```
CREATE TABLE play_evolutions
(
  id Number(10,0) Not Null Enable,
  hash VARCHAR2(255 Byte),
  applied_at Timestamp Not Null,
  apply_script clob,
  revert_script clob,
  state Varchar2(255),
  last_problem clob,
  CONSTRAINT play_evolutions_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

with generating table manually, evolutions are applied, but program stops with following stack trace:

```
Unexpected exception

NullPointerException: null
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:

->java.lang.NullPointerException: 

     play.api.db.evolutions.Evolution.<init>(Evolutions.scala:36)

     play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$$anonfun$databaseEvolutions$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:378)

     play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$$anonfun$databaseEvolutions$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:374)

     play.api.libs.Collections$.loop$1(Collections.scala:29)

     play.api.libs.Collections$.unfoldLeft(Collections.scala:33)

     play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.databaseEvolutions(Evolutions.scala:374)

     play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:332)

     play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:330)

     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)

     play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.evolutionScript(Evolutions.scala:330)

     play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:486)

     play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:531)

     play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:485)

     play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:483)

     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)

     play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:483)

     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)

     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)

     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)

     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)

     play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)

     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:142)

     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115)

     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)

     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115)

     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113)

     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)

     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113)

     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:105)

     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)

     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)

     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)

     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)

     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)

     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)

     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

Origin of this problem is empty `Downs` part in sql file.
I report it as issue [#3033](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3033) in play frame work community